# SQL: How to implement generic categories?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, database-design, select

I need to implement following categorization in SQL:

- group can contain multiple tests or multiple (child) groups
- test could be in multiple groups
- (child) group could be in multiple (parent) groups

... that means 2 x M:N relations. Following tables could store the group trees:

**TEST_TABLE**
test_id (pk), test_name

**GROUP_TABLE**
group_id (pk), group_name

**TEST_IN_GROUP_TABLE**
test_id (fk), group_id (fk)

**GROUP_RELATIONS_TABLE**
parent_group_id (fk), child_group_id (fk)

But:

- **How to list all tests in group?** This sounds to me impossibly difficult, since group could contain tests or sub-groups with another tests.
- Or how to modify tables to make such SELECT possible? I could create  additional **child_count** column in GROUP_TABLE. It will be auto-filled by trigger. But even with it it's hard nut for me.

Comment: The database will be in probably on MS SQL Server 2008 R2. (I am in logical model yet, I will do physical model later).

Comment: Then the design is fine. The test-group and 1-M:M-1 bridge table is correct, and so is the hierarchical table group-relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Common Table Expressions to first build up the group_ids of the group sought, then using that single list of groups, join through TEST_IN_GROUP_TABLE to the test table for all tests.

```
;with cte as (
    select group_id
    from GROUP_TABLE
    where group_id = 1
    union all
    select child_group_id
    from GROUP_RELATIONS_TABLE
    inner join cte on cte.group_id = GROUP_RELATIONS_TABLE.parent_group_id
)
select t.*
from cte
inner join TEST_IN_GROUP_TABLE tg on tg.group_id = cte.group_id
inner join TEST_TABLE t on t.test_id = tg.test_id
```